# Android Sqlite database table not created

Tags: android, sqlite

hello i'am new on mobile dev! I have a problem with SQLite ! i want to create 2 tables but the second table can't be created . 
I create a table without any problem but i have problem if i want to create another one ! if i do a getAllTableNames , my table is not created .  THis is my model ..

```
public class Model extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public Model(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Plat(C_IDplat INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , C_IDcategorie INTEGER , C_Nomplat TEXT , C_Photoplat TEXT , C_Descriptionplat TEXT) ");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Categorie(C_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , C_Nom TEXT , C_Photo TEXT , C_Description TEXT) ");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {


    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Categorie");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Plat");

    // recreate the tables
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}

public void save(Categorie C) {
    ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
    v.put("C_Nom", C.getNom());
    v.put("C_Photo", C.getPhoto());
    v.put("C_Description", C.getDescription());
    long id = C.getId();
    if (id == 0) {
        id = this.getWritableDatabase().insert("Categorie", null, v);
        C.setId(id);

    } else {

        this.getWritableDatabase().update("Categorie", v, "C_ID = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    }


}
```

check this ` */
public class Menus extends AppCompatActivity {

```
  Model m1 = new Model(this , "DB", null , 3); // i instaciate my model





Categorie pizza = new Categorie("Pizza" , R.drawable.pizza , "Les meilleurs pizza de Dakar " );
Categorie baguettes = new Categorie("Baguettes" , R.drawable.baguette , "Explosion de saveurs a prix mini");
Categorie pastas = new Categorie("Pastas" , R.drawable.pastas , "Laissez vous tenter ");
Categorie donuts = new Categorie("Donuts" , R.drawable.donuts , "Al dente et tellement genereuses");
Categorie snacks = new Categorie("Snacks" , R.drawable.snacks , "Un delice a chaque bouchée");
Categorie Boisson_gaz = new Categorie("Boissons Gazeuses" , R.drawable.gazeuse , "Pensez a vous desalterer");
Categorie Alcool = new Categorie("Alcool" , R.drawable.alcool , "De la bonne qualite");
Categorie Cocktail = new Categorie("Cocktail" , R.drawable.cocktail , "Decouvrez nos cocktails");
Categorie Boisson_chaude = new Categorie("Boissons chaudes" , R.drawable.chaude , "Un bon cafe ne fait jamais de mal");
Monplat plat1 = new Monplat("Renne","une bonne pizza " , R.drawable.pizza);
Monplat plat2 = new Monplat("Renne","une bonne pizza " , R.drawable.pizza);
Monplat plat3 = new Monplat("Renne","une bonne pizza " , R.drawable.pizza);





protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menus);





    List<String> listetable = m1.getAllTableName(); // i check here if my all table are being created but only the first table i createe yesterday is created
    Log.i("Liste" , "listeTable :"+listetable);
```

`

Comment: Please provide more information, which is the error message when you create the second table

Comment: Did you clear your app data before running your code? `onCreate` will only be called _once_

Comment: no , how to clear it ?

Comment: IT works ! i just change the database version

Comment: my oncreate was not being called , so i change the database and my upgrade method call my oncreate method